# Azure Front Door - Determine which origin is unavailable

Tags: azure, logging, health-check, azure-front-door

Have a Azure Front Door setup currently with 2 origin groups.
In each of the Origin Groups, I have added 1 origin.

The first origin group is working fine, and the Origin Health metric was at 100%.

I added a second origin group, which does not work, and the Origin Health is now 0.

However, the first endpoint works fine through Front Door. First question, should not this return in a Origin Health of 50% ? 1 out of 2 origins is unavailable for some reason.

I tried to figure out in the Portal, if you can see the actual status of the origins, but I have not been able to locate it.

Looking in the logs, FrontDoorHealthProbeLog, there actual is no info either, as far as I can see, on which of the thats unavailable.

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-diagnostics?pivots=front-door-standard-premium#health-probe-log) , I could guess that the "OriginName" could be the origin (URL/hostname of the backend/origin service), but that does not seem to be the case.

Can anyone point me in the direction of spotting which of the backends (origins) are down?
[image: Azure Logs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Metrics of your Front Door, apply splitting by Origin and you'll get this graph where you can see what the status of each origin is.

[image]